# Ухвалити чи прийняти закон?

Tags: словосполучення, стилістика

Натрапила на сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieslovo-prujmatu-pravula-vzhuvannya) на інформацію:

> Зокрема, треба говорити: брати до уваги, взяти участь, набувати форми, стати на бік, **ухвалити закон**. Натомість мовці помилково кажуть у цих висловах слово **«приймати»**.

Однак, в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjmaty) знаходимо:

> **ПРИЙМАТИ**, аю, аєш, недок., ПРИЙНЯТИ, рідко. ПРИНЯТИ і діал. ПРИЙМИТИ, прийму, приймеш, док., перех.
>   Приймати (прийняти) шлюб — те саме, що **Закон приймати (прийняти)** (див. закон). [Химка:]

Отже, як правильно: ПРИЙМАТИ чи УХВАЛИТИ закон?

Comment: Див. також: [«„Вирішувати“, „ухвалювати рішення“, or „приймати рішення“?»](/q/1058) (англ.).

Answer (score 2):

Краще не вживати вислів "прийняти закон", так як

> Слово "приймати" на місці там, де воно передає зміст "одержувати", "брати"(“Хліб святий приймаємо, а вас послухаємо” – Григорій Квітка-Основ’яненко).

А от із вживанням словосполучення "ухвалити закон" все гараз, так як

> замість вислову "прийняти постанову" краще вживати дієслова "ухвалити" або "постановити". Так само "ухвалити закон"

(див. [джерело](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53411/25746.html) — «Уроки державної мови» з газети «Хрещатик»).

Також те саме каже [проф. Пономарев](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-41932102), однак зазначає, що **можливі обидва варіанти**, але все ж віддавайте перевагу "ухваленим законам".

> Можна і так, і так, але краще ухвалити закон.

Comment: Чому краще не вживати, якщо це зазначено в Конституції України (Стаття 85, п.3)?

Answer (score 1):

**[Законодавчий процес](https://vrkadry.rada.gov.ua/uploads/documents/30668.pdf)** - це нормативно регламентована процедура **ухвалення закону**, яка складається з певніх стадій – самостійних, логічно завершених етапів і організаційно-технічних дій: ✓ Внесення; ✓ Розгляду; ✓ Прийняття (зміни); ✓ Оприлюднення та опублікування.

**Закон України** — нормативно-правовий акт, який **приймається Верховною Радою України** **більшістю в 226 голосів** (для законів, що стосуються внесення змін до Конституції, — 300 голосів) та підписується Президентом України.

> В Україні **прийняття законів** є компетенцією Верховної Ради. Народ
> України здійснює законодавчі повноваження через всеукраїнський
> референдум. Закон, прийнятий на референдумі, має вищу юридичну силу та
> не потребує будь-якого затвердження.
>
> Порядок прийняття законів здійснюється і [регламентується](https://lj.oa.edu.ua/articles/2016/n2/16naacpa.pdf) Конституцією
> України і Регламентом Верховної Ради України, відповідно до яких
> **[законодавча процедура](https://www.naiau.kiev.ua/files/kafedru/tdp/navch_pos_tdp.pdf)** в себе включає:
>
> – ***законодавчу ініціативу*** – звернення суб’єктів, визначених
> Конституцією України, до Верховної Ради стосовно прийняття нового
> закону, або зміни чинного закону, яке здійснюється шляхом внесення до
> Верховної Ради України законодавчої пропозиції, чи поправок до
> законопроектів;
>
> – ***підготовку проекту закону до розгляду*** його Верховною Радою
> України. Основними етапами підготовки є прийняття рішення щодо
> підготовки проекту, організаційно-технічне та фінансове забезпечення
> підготовки проекту, розроблення концепції законопроекту, підготовка
> тексту проекту закону та додатків до нього, наукова експертиза проекту
> закону, подання закону на розгляд Верховної Ради України суб’єктом
> права законодавчої ініціативи;
>
> – ***розгляд і обговорення проекту закону*** Верховною Радою України на
> пленарних засіданнях;
>
> – **прийняття закону Верховною Радою України**. Прийнятий закон
> підписує Голова Верховної Ради України не раніше двох і не пізніше
> п’яти днів з дня його подання;
>
> – ***введення в дію закону*** – визначається в його прикінцевих
> положеннях, або перехідних положеннях, або окремим законом.
> Конституційний закон і кодекс вводяться в дію окремими законами.
>  Прийнятий і підписаний Головою Верховної Ради України закон
> надсилається на підпис Президентові України, який підписує його, або
> може застосувати своє право на вето та повернути закон на повторний
> розгляд Верховною Радою України.

[ПОЛОЖЕННЯ
про порядок роботи з проектами законодавчих актів та
матеріалами, що містять законодавчі пропозиції, які
подаються на розгляд Верховної Ради України](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/668/95-%D0%BF%D0%B2#Text)

Отже, **Закон України** вважається **прийнятим** після того, як отримав більшість голосів депутатів Верховної Ради України. **Прийняття закону** є одним з етапів процедури **ухвалення закону**.